# Heroku unable to detect java 11

Tags: java, heroku

I am trying to deploy a java jar to heroku with heroku maven plugin.
I am using java 11 so I have added **system.properties** in the root folder(where pom.xml is present) and set **java.runtime.version=11**. However it doesn't seem to be working !

My plugin :

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includeTarget>false</includeTarget>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                    <processTypes>
                        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -jar ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar</web>
                    </processTypes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

When I do  **git push heroku master** it starts build process using jdk 8.

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.6.2... done
remote: -----> Executing Maven
remote:        $ mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
```

Eventually build fails with error :

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project ImpactHub_bot: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release ->
```

How do I set jdk verison to 11 ? I have also tried adding ${java.version} to configuration but it didn't help

Answer (score 3):

That's exactly how you are specifying the Java version, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#specifying-a-java-version

> You can specify a Java version by adding a file called
>   `system.properties` to your application.
>
> Set a property `java.runtime.version` in the file:
>
> ```
> java.runtime.version=11
> ```

I used it in [my project](https://github.com/NNTin/Red-kun/blob/master/system.properties) as well and it is working.

---

Make sure your `system.properties` is saved as `All Files`. Furthermore it should be at the root folder of your git repo.
It might have a `.txt` ending. If that fails [open a Support Ticket with Heroku](http://help.heroku.com/).

Comment: I identified the problem - its with the command interpretation  of git push heroku master, I has a feature branch where i made all the changes and was trying to blindly execute master.- so changed it to feature and it picked java 11